# How to auto install missing module in python?

Tags: python, linux, configure, autoconf

I want to release my simple python script which use some extended module such as `argparse` and `watchdog`. I don't think it reasonable to make the assumption that user of my script already has these modules installed. So I think I should include a configure script to test user environment (if I can automatically install these missing modules, that couldn't be better:P) in the release.

My question is: is there any utilities like `configure` for c program. If no such things, is it possible to adapt `configure` to python environment? Otherwise I have to compose some from scratch:(.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to automatically download required modules in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634874/easiest-way-to-automatically-download-required-modules-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use PIP with a text file stating all required modules. 
like so:

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

see:
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/), and specifically [this](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#requirement-objects) documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/) to install the modules. PIP is replacement of `easy_install`.

Comment: What does pip do better than easy_install?

Comment: Hi @NickStinemates, I write what written in the PIP page. **pip installs packages. Python packages. An easy_install replacement**. If you want to discover more then please check site http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/